# re.sub for only captured group

Tags: python, regex

Given the string:

```
s = '<Operation dedupeMode="normal" name="update">'
```

I would like to change the dedupeMode to manual. For example, the end result should be:

```
s = '<Operation dedupeMode="manual" name="update">'
```

Is there a way with `re.sub` to only replace the captured group and nothing else? Here is what I have so far, but it replaces everything and not just the captured group:

```
import re
s = '''<Operation dedupMode="normal" name="update">'''
re.sub(r'dedupMode="(normal|accept|manual|review)"', "manual", s)
# '<Operation manual name="update">'
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132903/11258117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either switch the capturing group to capture dedupMode=" and the ending `"`

```
(dedupMode=")(?:normal|accept|manual|review)(")
```

And replace with

```
\1manual\2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wgzOUM/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4mwCUK)

Or perhaps use lookarounds

```
(?<=dedupMode=")(?:normal|accept|manual|review)(?=")
```

And replace with

```
manual
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pfFhNs/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6OGpQw)

For the options you could use a non capturing group `(?:`

**Note** that `manual` is also present in the alternation which might be omitted as it is the same as the replacement value.

Comment: thanks. Yea, I was hoping it could be done without a lookbehind, but it seems that that might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just make a small change in your original code and that would work. Change the string to replace with:
`"manual"` **`-->`** `'dedupMode="manual"'`

```py
import re
s = '''<Operation dedupMode="normal" name="update">'''
re.sub(r'dedupMode="(normal|accept|manual|review)"', 'dedupMode="manual"', s)
```

**Output**:

```
'<Operation dedupMode="manual" name="update">'
```

Comment: @David542 Here's another option. It requires least change in your original code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this is by far the simplest approach!