# Replace a character enclosed with lowercase letters

Tags: python, regex

All the examples I've found on stack overflow **are too complicated for me to reverse engineer**.

Consider this toy example

```
s = "asdfasd a_b dsfd"
```

I want `s = "asdfasd a'b dsfd"`

That is: find two characters separated by an underscore and replace that underscore with an apostrophe

Attempt:

```
re.sub("[a-z](_)[a-z]","'",s)
# "asdfasd ' dsfd"
```

I thought the `()` were supposed to solve this problem?

Even more confusing is the fact that it seems that we successfully found the character we want to replace:

```
re.findall("[a-z](_)[a-z]",s)
#['_']
```

why doesn't this get replaced?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use look-ahead and look-behind patterns:

```
re.sub("(?<=[a-z])_(?=[a-z])","'",s)
```

Look ahead/behind patterns have zero width and thus do not replace anything.

**UPD:**

- The problem was that `re.sub` will replace the whole matched expression, including the preceding and the following letter.
- `re.findall` was still matching the whole expression, but it also had a group (the parenthesis inside), which you observed. The whole match was still `a_b`
- lookahead/lookbehind expressions check that the search is preceded/followed by a pattern, but do not include it into the match.
- another option was to create several groups, and put those groups into the replacement: `re.sub("([a-z])_([a-z])", r"\1'\2", s)`

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why I was able to find the pattern, but not replace it?

Comment: @RNs_Ghost added an update. Let me know if it needs more details

Answer (score 2):

When using `re.sub`, the text to keep must be captured, the text to remove should not.

Use

```
re.sub(r"([a-z])_(?=[a-z])",r"\1'",s)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vU8ogh/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolatYwVZBKbE4JQ2IFRLjkxRSitNSlLgKijLzSjSKUvWKS5M0ipQ0ohN1q2I14zXsbSEsJZ0ipRhDdSWdYk3N//8B):

```
import re
s = "asdfasd a_b dsfd"
print(re.sub(r"([a-z])_(?=[a-z])",r"\1'",s))
```

Output:

```
asdfasd a'b dsfd
```

Answer (score 0):

The `re.sub` will replace everything it matched .

There's a more general way to solve your problem , and you do not need to re-modify your regular expression.

Code below:

```
import re


s = 'Data: year=2018, monthday=1, month=5, some other text'
reg = r"year=(\d{4}), monthday=(\d{1}), month=(\d{1})"


r = "am_replace_str"
def repl(match):
    _reg = "|".join(match.groups())
    return re.sub(_reg, r,match.group(0)) if _reg else r

# 
re.sub(reg,repl, s)
```

output: `'Data: year=am_replace_str, monthday=am_replace_str, month=am_replace_str, some other text'`

Of course, if your case does not contain groups , your code may like this :

```
import re


s = 'Data: year=2018, monthday=1, month=5, some other text'
reg = r"year=(\d{4}), monthday=(\d{1}), month=(\d{1})"


r = "am_replace_str"
def repl(match):
    _reg = "|".join(match.groups())
    return re.sub(_reg, r,match.group(0))

# 
re.sub(reg,repl, s)
```